# Grails 5.2.x vs Grails 5.3.x

Tags: grails

I was using Grails 5.2.4 with the Grails Quartz plugin. The Quartz plugin was outdated (2.0.8) but still worked. I saw there was a Grails 5.3.4.  I upgraded my project to 5.3.4.  The Quartz plugin no longer worked.

I switched back to 5.2.4 for now.

What makes 5.3.x not working with the Quartz plugin?

Comment: Have you tried `org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.2.1` and `org.grails.plugins:quartz:2.0.13`? It's working with Grails 5.3.3

Comment: Yes, I did try different versions with 5.3.4.  None of them worked with 5.3.4.  As soon as I switched back to 5.2.4. all those different versions worked again.

Comment: `org.grails.plugins:quartz:2.0.13` is newer then `2.0.8` which you mention in your post. I recommend double checking it

Comment: I have tried a bunch of different Quartz versions including 2.0.13.  You said 5.3.3 worked.  So, I switched to 5.3.3 for trying it out.  The plugin works with 5.3.3 but not 5.3.4.  5.3.4 giving error - ...Error creating bean with name 'grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob'... No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.Object' available...

Comment: I upgraded Grails to 5.3.5 and it's still working so I can not replicate your issue. Have you tried to create a new, PoC project, with minimum dependencies and create example job to replicate this issue? If so, please share the repo